# Exploding nested array in PySpark

Tags: multidimensional-array, pyspark, explode

I am trying to reach to the 3rd cn Array (highlighted) in, please suggest and logic and sample code.
[image]

Comment: What is your current approach? Could you provide your code?

Comment: I got the logic and my code is working, I have to see the element present in the dataframe and then explode the array, let me share the code which worked for me...

Comment: 'cn_cn_cn_arr=cn_cn_arr.select(cn_cn_arr.p_id,
                                                            cn_cn_arr._id,                                                        
                                                            explode(cn_cn_arr.cn_cn.cn).alias('cn_cn_cn')
                                                          )'

Answer (score 0):

To solve the nested array, first see the schema of the preceding array, keep the notice of the elements and then follow the following logic to get the array exploded.

`explode(preceding_array.first_lv_element.nested_array_name)`

I used the below code

```
cn_cn_cn_arr=cn_cn_arr.select(cn_cn_arr.pid,                                                        
                                 cn_cn_arr.id,                                                        
                                                          explode(cn_cn_arr.cn_cn.cn).alias('cn_cn_cn'))
```